# I installed pod file Siren in swift 4.2 .But Siren has no member wail error occur! How to fix this solution?

Tags: swift4.2, siren

I am working in Swift4.2 and import siren in my project .BUt error occur.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 85/255.0, blue: 127/255.0, alpha: 1)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        //        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white,NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Medium", size: 16)!]
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffset(horizontal: 0, vertical: -60), for:UIBarMetrics.default)
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

        IQKeyboardManager .shared().isEnabled = true
        IQKeyboardManager .shared().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
        IQKeyboardManager .shared().isEnableAutoToolbar = false

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()


        let mainview = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        let nav = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: mainview)
        SideMenu = LGSideMenuController.init(rootViewController: nav)
        SideMenuView = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SideMenuViewController") as! SideMenuViewController
        SideMenu.rightViewStatusBarVisibleOptions = .onAll
        let rect = SideMenuView.view.frame;
        SideMenuView.view.frame = rect


        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

//Setup siren

         Siren.shared.wail()

}


        return true
    }
```